# Template 'content template 'checked' defined by XXX returned null for args: '[]'

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

I'm using Geb and Spock to writing my Integration Test and here are my codes:

ITCase.groovy:

```
waitFor {
    documents && documents[index]?.displayed && documents[index].checked?.displayed
}
documents[index].checked.click()
```

Page.groovy:

```
static content = {
    documents {
        moduleList DocumentListItemModule, $("#documents-list table tbody tr")
    }
}
```

DocumentListItemModule.groovy:

```
static content = {
    checked { $(".tst-doc-checkbox").find { it.displayed }}
}
```

Usually it worked well, but occasionally there will be error at line `documents[index].checked.click()`:

```
Template 'content template 'checked' defined by XXX returned null for args: '[]'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and solved it by [waiting](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#content-dsl-wait) for the element. So in your case, I would try something like

```
static content = {
    checked(wait: true) { $(".tst-doc-checkbox").find { it.displayed }}
}
```